# Just wondering is there any convention when coding Controller/Model in Laravel?

Tags: php

In Laravel, I usually investigate relative model and its life-cycle activity.

For example, `Cat` has many `Poop` . So, what I thinking is, `Cat` model should manage `Poop`'s creation and destruction because actual cat produce actual poop.

```
class Cat extends Model
{
    public function makePoop($options = [])
    {
        // make and return poop
    }
}
```

Then, controller is like..

```
class CatController extends Controller
{
    // Request Receptor
    public create(Request $request, Cat $cat)
    {
        // make opitons array
        $options = [
            'size'=>$request->input('size'), // other things..
        ];

        // deligates making poop..
        $result = $cat->makePoop($options);

        // Behavior check..
        if($result instanceof App\Poop) {
            \Session::flash('isPoopSuccess', true);
            return view('~~');
        }
        else {
            \Session::flash('isPoopSuccess', false);
            return view('~~')->withError('poop', 'Your poop is pooped');
        }
    }
}
```

What is wonder is, is this a bad practice? Are there some improvements? What I do know more??

The reason why I write this question is because.. I'm not developer so can't ask anyone around me..